# Выбрать только активных пользователей при отправке на группу в Postfix

Tags: active-directory, ldap, postfix, dovecot

Есть рабочая связка postfix + dovecot + AD.
Как сделать так, чтобы при отправке на группу, в к-ую могут входить как активные, так и отключенные пол-ли
не было бы попытки отправки почты на отключенных пол-лей?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Postfix через ldap фильтр выбирает участников группы рассылки из AD? Если да, то измените фильтр, который будет отдавать только активных пользователей. Погуглите правильный синтаксис для этого. Ключевое слово в нем userAccountControl, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @de_frag  
Я тоже думал, что это просто.  
Но вот так отбирает member-ов из группы, но сделать, чтобы отбирало только активных нет возможности:  
query_filter     = (&(objectClass=group)(member=*)(mail=%s)); special_result_attribute = member;  leaf_result_attribute = mail

Comment: Вот такой фильтр выбирает из AD 2012 (полагаю, что и с другими AD будет работать) активных пользователей группы: (&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=myGroup,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=example,DC=loc)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))

Comment: @de_frag  
Спасибо.  
Попробовал схему с помощью pipemap:{ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group_dn_maps.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group_members_maps.cf}.  
Сперва выбрал DN группы:
query_filter     = (&(mail=%s)(member=*)) ; result_attribute = distinguishedName. Затем использовал полученный результат для выборки только активных пол-лей из группы:  
query_filter = (&(memberOf=%s)(objectClass=person)(mail=*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))  
Работает, если в группе НЕТ вложенных групп. А надо, чтобы и со вложенными группами работало.

Answer (score 0):

Решено:

```
cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
...
virtual_alias_maps = pipemap:{ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group_members.cf}
...

cat /etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group.cf
...
query_filter     = (&(mail=%s)(objectClass=group)(member=*))
result_attribute = distinguishedName
...

cat /etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group_members.cf
...
query_filter     = (&(userPrincipalName=*)(mail=*)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=%s)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
result_attribute = mail
...
```

Проверка:

```
postmap -vfq "group@doma.in" "pipemap:{ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap/ad_virtual_group_members.cf}"
```

Применяем:

```
posfix reload
```